# additonal line space in textview

Tags: android, textview, fragment, space

I have a viewpager and inside of it a textview.
For filling pages of viewpager I should measure textview line height with a textpaint.
When viewpager adapter is set, my problem is that in 2 difference page line number is equal but page textview height is different and I want textview fit to page,It is happen in android 4.4.2 and Below, how can I solve this problem.
Notice that I can't use maxLine ellipsize or other solution like them because textview lines number is uncertain.
[image: image 1]

[image: image2]

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context="ru.appheads.pagesplitterapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pages"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="1dp"></LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/pageSeekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="50"
        android:progress="0"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sizeSeekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="45"
        android:progress="0"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/lineSpaceSeekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="40"
        android:progress="0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="left" >

</TextView>
```

PageFragment :

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    private final String PAGE_TEXT = "PAGE_TEXT";
    private final String TEXT_SIZE = "TEXT_SIZE";
    private final String LINE_SPACE = "LINE_SPACE";

    public PageFragment newInstance(CharSequence pageText, float textSize, float lineSpace) {
        PageFragment frag = new PageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putCharSequence(PAGE_TEXT, pageText);
        args.putFloat(TEXT_SIZE, textSize);
        args.putFloat(LINE_SPACE, lineSpace);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        CharSequence text = getArguments().getCharSequence(PAGE_TEXT);
        float textSize = getArguments().getFloat(TEXT_SIZE);
        float lineSpace = getArguments().getFloat(LINE_SPACE);
        TextView pageView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, container, false);
        pageView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, UnitConverter.spToPixels(getContext(), textSize));
        pageView.setText(text);
        Typeface plain = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Roboto_Medium.ttf");
        pageView.setTypeface(plain);
        pageView.setLineSpacing(UnitConverter.spToPixels(getActivity(),lineSpace), 1f);
        pageView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        return pageView;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, Its device specific issue.

For better output in all devices you should use `ScrollView` as a container of your `TextView`.

In addition, If you want to add some `extra space` between text `lines` then you can use `textView.setLineSpacing()` programmatically or from `XML` you can use attribute `android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"` to `TextView` for extra spacing.

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 1):

you have change in your base layout LinearLayout to RelativeLayout try this:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                tools:context="ru.appheads.pagesplitterapp.MainActivity">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/pages"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/obttom_layout"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/obttom_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#000000"></LinearLayout>

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/pageSeekbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:max="50"
                        android:progress="0" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/sizeSeekbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:max="45"
                        android:progress="0" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/lineSpaceSeekbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:max="40"
                        android:progress="0" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Page Xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:id="@+id/pages_txt"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="left" >

                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: thx for your answer but my problem is that in 2 difference page ,line number is equal but page height is different

Comment: ohh, so it can be device specific issue, you have to put your page text view inside scrollview, updated my answer, plz try it once.

Comment: but i dont want to use scrollview and textview most fit to page.